# How to have a derived class use the base implemention to satisfy an interface

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have the following two interfaces, which are not part of an inheritance hierarchy. I then have two concrete classes, one which derives from the other.

```
class ICar {
    public:
    virtual void drive() = 0;
};

class IFastCar {
    public:
    virtual void drive() = 0;
    virtual void driveFast() = 0;
};

class Car : public virtual ICar {
    public:
    void drive() {};
};

class FastCar : public Car, public virtual IFastCar {
    public:
    void driveFast() {};
};

int main()
{
    FastCar fc;
    fc.drive();
    fc.driveFast();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
error: cannot declare variable `fc' to be of type `FastCar'
error:   because the following virtual functions are abstract:
error:  virtual void IFastCar::drive()
```

My program will work if I write a function in FastCar to delegate drive() to the base class

```
void drive() { Car::drive(); }
```

Is is possible to have FastCar compile without writing methods to delegate to the base class?

Note: ICar and IFastCar are created by two different teams and are in two different projects. The teams have agreed on common method signatures for operations which are shared. I have used inheritance in the implementation classes to attempt to reuse the parts of the implementation which are the same.

Comment: I think Herb Sutter's [Multiple Inheritance, Part 3](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/039.htm) might be helpful here, as well as another thread with a somewhat similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616380/multiple-inheritance-virtual-function-mess

Comment: In your example, FastCar inherits two unrelated interfaces (iCar and iFastCar). Both these interfaces define a *different* pure virtual method drive(). Is that the intent, or should IFastCar inherit from ICar ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that there's multiple inheritance taking place here ... even though `FastCar` is derived from `Car`, the version of `drive()` in the base-class `Car` only overrides `ICar::drive()`, not `IFastCar::drive()`.  Thus, since you are deriving `FastCar` from `IFastCar`, you will need to, at some point, define a function in `FastCar` that also overrides the pure virtual abstract method `IFastCar::drive()` ... The inherited `Car::drive()` will not automatically override `IFastCare::drive()` since it does not inherit from that class.  `IFastCar::drive()` and `ICar::drive()` are two different pure abstract virtual functions that need to be overridden separately.  If you want to make the interface for `IFastCar::drive()` call your inherited `Car::drive()` function, then you will need to delegate that inherited function as you've done within a version of `FastCar::drive()` that specifically calls its base-class' version of `drive()`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Car` does not implement `IFastCar::drive` but only `ICar::drive`. The first design question is why does `IFastCar` not extend the `ICar` interface and redefines the same operation?

If for some reason that is not an option, then the simplest thing that you can do is actually implement `IFastCar::drive()` in `FastCar` by forwarding the request to the `Car::drive` method:

```
void FastCar::drive() {
   Car::drive();
}
```

Comment: That won't work. I assume you mean `FastCar` instead of `IFastCar`.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `virtual` inheritance here is spurrious, and is a red herring.  `virtual` inheritance is used to derive from common base classes only once; **not** to bring in only one declaration for matching member signatuires.

So, your `FastCar` concrete class actually has 3 members, not 2:

```
virtual void ICar::drive()
virtual void IFastCar::drive()
virtual void IFastCar::driveFast()
```

The two different `drive()` appear to be related, so your design appears to be flawed.  You don't want `virtual` inheritance -- you probably want `IFastCar` to derive from `ICar`.

```
class ICar {
    public:
    virtual void drive() = 0;
};

class IFastCar : public ICar {
    public:
    virtual void driveFast() = 0;
};

class Car : public virtual ICar {
    public:
    void drive() {};
};

class FastCar : public IFastCar {
    public:
    void drive() {};
    void driveFast() {};
};

int main()
{
    FastCar fc;
    fc.drive();
    fc.driveFast();
    return 0;
}
```

If you then wanted `Car` to implement some basic functionality that `FastCar` will employ, then you can derive `FastCar` from `Car`, and *that* is why you would want `virtual` inheritance.  Just remember to apply `virtual` inheritance at the point just below the top of the diamond:

```
class ICar {
    public:
    virtual void drive() = 0;
};

class IFastCar : virtual public ICar {
    public:
    virtual void driveFast() = 0;
};

class Car : public virtual ICar {
    public:
    void drive() {};
};

class FastCar : public IFastCar, public Car {
    public:
    void driveFast() {};
};

int main()
{
    FastCar fc;
    fc.drive();
    fc.driveFast();

    ICar* fc_a = new FastCar;
    fc_a->drive();  // invokes Car::drive() via domination

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile & run the above code you will get the desired behavior, but at the cost of a compiler warning.  On MSVC10 it reads:

```
1>main.cpp(19): warning C4250: 'FastCar' : inherits 'Car::Car::drive' via dominance
1>          main.cpp(13) : see declaration of 'Car::drive'
```

This is a warning that your implementation inheritance architecture might be screwed up.  And in fact, in most cases it probably is (although in this case not).  This can get awful confusing real fast, especially to a maintenance programmer years from now trying to figure out your code.  To clear up this confusion and avoid all the compiler warnings, I much prefer (as a rule) **delegation** to a sister class rather than implementation inheritance.

```
class ICar {
    public:
    virtual void drive() = 0;
};

class IFastCar : virtual public ICar {
    public:
    virtual void driveFast() = 0;
};

class ICarImpl 
{
public:
    void drive_impl() {};
};

class IFastCarImpl
{
public :
    void driveFast_impl() {};
};

class Car : public virtual ICar, protected ICarImpl {
    public:
    void drive() { drive_impl(); }
};

class FastCar : public IFastCar, protected ICarImpl, protected IFastCarImpl {
    public:
    void driveFast() { driveFast_impl(); }
    void drive() { drive_impl(); }
};

int main()
{
    FastCar fc;
    fc.drive();
    fc.driveFast();

    ICar* fc_a = new FastCar;
    fc_a->drive();  

    return 0;
}
```

This accomplishes the usual goal of implementation inheritance -- keeping just one common set of code that can be shared across multiple concrete classes, making maintenance easier.

Comment: Maybe I should be using `private` inheritance for the sister classes here, rather than `protected`...

Answer (score 0):

Since ICar and IFastCar are always cars, you could have IFastCar which derives from ICar,then Car and FastCar implemented like you did.

```
class ICar {
    public:
    virtual void drive() = 0;
};

class IFastCar : ICar 
{
    public:
    virtual void drive() = 0;
    virtual void driveFast() = 0;
};

class Car : ICar {
    public:
    void drive()
    {
        cout << "driving a normal car" << endl;
    }
};

class FastCar : IFastCar
{
    public:
    void drive()
    {
        cout << "driving a fast car the normal way" << endl;
    }

    void driveFast()
    {
        cout << "driving a fast car at top speed" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FastCar fc;

    fc.drive();
    fc.driveFast();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is about avoiding having to implement `FastCar::drive`, which can be tackled in an approach similar to what you provide inheritance in `IFastCar` from `ICar` would have to be virtual, and you will need to remove the `virtual void drive() = 0;` from `IFastCar` (and then you can remove the implementation of `FastCar::drive()`)