# What are the Pros and Cons of having Multiple Inheritance?

Tags: multiple-inheritance

What are the pros and cons of having multiple inheritance?

**And** why don't we have multiple inheritance in C#?

**UPDATE**
Ok so it is currently avoided because of the issue with clashes resolving which parent method is being called etc.  Surely this is a problem for the programmer to resolve.  Or maybe this could be resolve simularly as SQL where there is a conflict more information is required  i.e.  ID might need to become Sales.ID to resolve a conflict in the query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225929/what-is-the-exact-problem-with-multiple-inheritance - seems like a similar question

Answer (score 6):

Here is a good discussion on the pitfalls of multiple inheritance:

[Why should I avoid multiple inheritance in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406081/why-should-i-avoid-multiple-inheritance-in-c)

Here is a discussion from the C# team on why they decided not to allow multiple inheritance:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/85562.aspx
- http://dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/unknownreference/archive/2003/09/04/1401.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It's just another tool in the toolbox.  Sometimes, it is exactly the right tool.  If it is, having to find a workaround because the language actually prohibits it is a pain and leads to good opportunities to screw it up.

Pros and cons can only be found for a concrete case.  I guess that it's quite rare to actually fit a problem, but who are the language designers to decide how I am to tackle a specific problem?

Comment: Well in C# it isn't a Tool in the box yet! :)

Comment: +1, but from my understanding, it's only the only right choice in rare few cases.

Comment: Just as a "typical textbook example":  A house cat is both a mammal and a pet.  Expressing this as composition is awkward at best.  There are mammals that aren't pets, and pets that aren't mammals.  As a pet, a cat could have an owner, a loyalty stat, a tax number.  As a mammal, it could have feeding status, length overall, tail length, fur colour.

Answer (score 3):

I will give a pro here based on a C++ report-writer I've been [converting to REALbasic](http://code.google.com/p/rbrw-core/) (which has interfaces but only single-inheritance).

Multiple inheritance makes it easier to compose classes from small mixin base classes that implement functionality and have properties to remember state. When done right, you can get a lot of reuse of small code without having to copy-and-paste similar code to implement interfaces.

Fortunately, REALbasic has *extends* methods which are like the *extension methods* recently added to C# in C# 3.0. These help a bit with the problem, especially as they can be applied to arrays. I still ended up with some class hierarchies being deeper as a result of folding in what were previously multiply-inherited classes.

Answer (score 1):

The main con is that if two classes have a method with the same name, the new subclass doesn't know which one to call.

In C# you can do a form of multiple inheritance by including instances of each parent object within the child.

```
class MyClass
{
    private class1 : Class1;
    private class2: Class2;

    public MyClass
    {
        class1 = new Class1;
        class2 = new Class2;
    }
    // Then, expose whatever functionality you need to from there.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit from something you are asserting that your class is of that (base) type  in every way except that you may implement something slightly differently or *add* something to it, its actually extremely rare that your class *is* 2 things at once. Usually it just has behavour common to 2 or more things, and a better way to describe that generally is to have your class implement multiple interfaces. (or possibly encapsulation, depending on your circumstances)

Answer (score 0):

It's one of those help-me-to-not-shoot-myself-in-the-foot quirks, much like in Java.

Although it is nice to extend fields and methods from multiple sources (imagine a Modern Mobile Phone, which inherits from MP3 Players, Cameras, Sat-Navs, and the humble Old School Mobile Phone), clashes cannot be resolved by the compiler alone.