# C# Implementing methods from an interface

Tags: c#, console-application

i am creating a console app that makes use of inheritance to access methods in an interface which i am also creating. This will be the interface with the methods. (Code still to be added.) EDIT: I am creating an application that captures transport booking info for aircraft and trains. CAircraftBookings, CTrainBookings are booking classes that will contain and manage bookings made for Aicraft/Trains.

```
namespace Vehicle_Bookings
{
public interface IVehichlesBookings : CAircraftBookings, CTrainBookings
{
    public int Add
    {
    }

    public int Update
    {
    }

    public int Delete
    {
    }

    public int Retrieve
    {
    }
}
```

}

Now in my console app, the user selects the appropriate choice which will be Adding, Updating, Deleting and Retrieving. The choices will then go as follows:

```
switch (choice)
        {
            case "1": 



                break;

            case "2":



                break;

            case "3":



                break;

            case "4":



                break;
        }
        while (choice != "5")
```

How would i go about implementing specific methods from that interface. If the user presses 1 for choice 1, the method Add will be used. If they press 2 the update method will be used etc.

Comment: Your `interface` is not valid C# syntax.

Comment: You should not derive from CAircraftBookings (looks like it's a class). This looks like someone needs to do some programming on school. :)

Comment: What are `CAircraftBookings, CTrainBookings`?

Comment: I will be deriving and implementing booking classes for aircraft and trains from the IVehicleBookings class

Comment: Since you are already writing code to do hardcoded differentiation between the possible options, simply call the actual method you want to call, in each of the `case` sections...

Comment: I agree with Jeroen. Also, you refer to a console app. An interface should be implemented by one or more classes. Which is your class that will implement your interface?

Comment: I didn't want to make the assumption the other guys did. I simply thought you are not aware of the C# naming conventions. It is a fact that an interface cannot extend a class. It's like saying that pigs fly. Just because it sounds like words which do not violate grammar (we're not saying "pigs flyes" which would be incorrect from a grammar point of view) it doesn't mean it can happen.

Comment: An interface can't have implementations for the methods. Also CAircraftBookings, CTrainBookings will need to be interfaces themselves. You should try this in the compiler first.

Answer (score 2):

"I will be deriving and implementing booking classes for aircraft and trains from the IVehicleBookings class"

I think this is what you want:

```
public interface IVehichlesBookings
{
    int Add();
    int Update();
    int Delete();
    int Retrieve();
}

public class CAircraftBookings : IVehichlesBookings
{
    public int Add()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Update()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Delete()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Retrieve()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CTrainBookings : IVehichlesBookings
{
    public int Add()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Update()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Delete()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Retrieve()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

An interface `IVehicleBookings` that defines all kinds of things you can do with "vehicle bookings", and `CAircraftBookings` and `CTrainBookings` will decide how those things are done.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming VehiclesBooking is a class that implements IVehiclesBooking:

```
IVehiclesBooking vehiclesBooking = new VehiclesBooking();

switch (choice)
        {
            case "1": 
            vehiclesBooking.Add();
            break;

            case "2":
            vehiclesBooking.Update();
            break;

...
```

Comment: You mean `IVehiclesBooking vehiclesBooking = new CAircraftBookings()` or `new CTrainBookings()`

Answer (score 1):

I think i'm doing someones homework :)

As I can advise you, you should read about interfaces and how to use them. Look here: [Why do we use Interface? Is it only for Standardization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026054/why-do-we-use-interface-is-it-only-for-standardization)

I think the definition of the interface is right, **except** it should not derive from a class. You should derive from the interface.

example:  **PSEUDO**

```
public interface IVehichlesBookings
{
    // members.
}

public class CAircraftBookings : IVehichlesBookings
{
}

public class CTrainBookings : IVehichlesBookings
{
}
```

This means, that a `CAircraftBookings` supports the interface `IVehichlesBookings`, so it should have implement those `IVehichlesBookings` members. Next you can handle an instance of `CTrainBookings` or `CAircraftBookings` as `IVehichlesBookings`.

And you need to construct it like this:

```
IVehichlesBookings booking = new CTrainBookings();

char key = Console.ReadKey();

switch(key)
{
    case '1':
        booking.Add(...);
        break;
}
```

Your turn..