# Advantages of multiple inheritance over interface

Tags: c++, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why to use Interfaces ? Multiple Inheritance vs Interfaces ? Benefits of Interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531292/why-to-use-interfaces-multiple-inheritance-vs-interfaces-benefits-of-interfa)

In which programming situations multiple inheritance has an advantage over interfaces?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531292/why-to-use-interfaces-multiple-inheritance-vs-interfaces-benefits-of-interfa

Comment: Advantages depend on context. Given situation A MI has an advantage while in situation B Interface are advantages. Use the appropriate technique for the situation. Without more context it is imposable to answer as asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whenever you need common behaviour from two distinct classes. Interface just carry "method signatures", whereas classes carry actual behaviour. Multiple inheritance greatly helps to reduce boilerplate code.

I am no longer a C++ programmer (30kg ago I was). I went from C++ to Java to Scala... where traits were introduced. They shine a new light on multiple inheritance (even to people who though that it was an invention from the devil).

Answer (score 0):

Very short, to the bone difference:

Interfaces: implement multiple interfaces to support different 'contracts'.

Multiple inheritance: inherit from ready made classes to have ready-made behavior of that classes.

BTW, that two aren't comparable in a way you ask...

Answer (score -1):

The advantages are not entirely clear to me. [What is the exact problem with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225929/what-is-the-exact-problem-with-multiple-inheritance)

The benefits

> We have presented examples of multiple inheritance that show that it can have advantages when you can separate object characteristics into nonoverlapping sets. Multiple inheritance then lets you create complex classes using only the characteristics that you need, without a proliferation of base classes.

Are explained in http://opendylan.org/books/dpg/db_293.html

Comment: Your answer consists entirely of links and quotes. -1