# Why is there no 'WebElement' class in C# for Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

As per the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/), there is in fact no class called `WebElement` when using Selenium with C#.NET, even though there exists an interface called `IWebElement` which has almost the same functionality. In contrast, when using Selenium with Java, for example, we have the `WebElement` class readily available.

What is the purpose of this change in implementation? Why have an interface over a separate class?

Comment: `WebElement` in Java is also an interface https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IWebElement` is an interface that basically [describes a contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914802/why-i-should-go-for-interfaces-in-c-sharp-when-i-can-implement-the-methods-direc) which `IWebElement` implementations must follow. But, in Selenium, there is, for example, a [`RemoteWebElement` class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/?topic=html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebElement.htm) that implements the `IWebElement` interface.