# Re-instantiate interface reference on run time with the underlying type

Tags: c#

I'm using interfaces for unit testing in my project.
My interface have functions as well as properties.
I will be creating the object of interface class at the app startup as dependency and will be using throughout the application life cycle.
Is it possible to re-instantiate the class pointing to interface on run time with the underlying type?

For example.
This is what i do at app startup.

```
IPerson iperson = new Person();
```

Now once my API's are getting called i want to reinstatement this object again as per business logic.
So again in my API logic how would i know what object type my interface is pointing to?
Can i do something like this

```
// Type could be anything like Person,Person1,Person2 as all these classes implementing IPerson
Type p = iperson.Type 
 iperson = new p();
```

Comment: `iperson = Activator.CreateInstance(iperson.GetType()) as IPerson`

Comment: @sureshrajput You don't instantiate an interface. An interface is not an object: it is a contract specification. It is an abstraction of the reality abstraction. You instantiate a class to have an object, then you can cast it into an interface reference. [What is the difference between an interface and a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914802/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-a-class-and-why-i-should-use-an/58174007#58174007)

Comment: @OlivierRogier The first comment is that i was looking for.

Comment: @sureshrajput Yes.

Comment: @Alberto Thank you. Is there any performance issue or bad impact of using Activator.CreateInstance ?

Comment: @sureshrajput as long as you don't pass any parameters to the constructor, the performance impact should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you do it wrong way. Reflection is for specific cases, and you have low probability to encounter this case.

I suggest you to create some generic `IFactory<T> where T : new(), IInterface` with method `Create<T>()`. If you will operate factory instead of direct type, it would give you an option to create new instances on-the-fly.