# Can a C# class call an interface's default interface method from its own implementation?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

If I have a default interface method like this:

```cs
public interface IGreeter
{
    void SayHello(string name) => System.Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}!");
}
```

Can I have my concrete implementation call that default method?

```cs
public class HappyGreeter : IGreeter
{
    public void SayHello(string name)
    {
        // what can I put here to call the default method?
        System.Console.WriteLine("I hope you're doing great!!");
    }
}
```

So that calling:

```cs
var greeter = new HappyGreeter() as IGreeter;
greeter.SayHello("Pippy");
```

Results in this:

```cs
// Hello Pippy!
// I hope you're doing great!!
```

Indeed [Calling C# interface default method from implementing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761799/calling-c-sharp-interface-default-method-from-implementing-class) shows that I can call method that my class *does not implement*, but as somewhat expected adding call to `((IGreeter)this).SayHello(name);` inside `HappyGreeter.SaysHello` causes stack overflow.

Comment: Let me ask yo ua stupid question: if you could not call the default method, how would it EVER be called?

Comment: I don't think that's a stupid question at all.  This is my first time working with default interface members.  But, the way I would call that is by casting my concrete instance as the interface with the default member.  It's pretty cool.  I've often wanted to see traits in C# and I think this is going to be a powerful addition once I get used to it.

Comment: Duplicate. t his acutally is not stupid and quite tricky - but also answered somewhere else. Interesting.

Comment: Is it possible to un-close it or do I need to re-ask it?  Thanks a lot for taking the time to moderate the community.  In this case, I think it was probably mis-labeled.  I looked pretty hard for an answer to this question.

Comment: `Can I have my concrete implementation call that default method?` I don't believe so, although there looks to be plans to add that through `base`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods

Comment: This can be achieved by inheriting from the class or abstract class, where you can access "default" methods via `base.method()`

Comment: @Fabio Can you show us how that would look? I can't picture it.

Comment: @mjwills, _by inheriting from the class or abstract class with virtual methods_ instead of interface.

Comment: @Fabio Oh you mean without using interfaces *at all*. That wasn't entirely clear on your comment (due to use of "default"). I read it as having an interface, an implementing class then one inheriting from it.

Comment: @D.Patrick You can declare in the inteface `IGreeter` a static method that implements functionality of the method `SayHello`. And then this method can be call from the class  `HappyGreeter`. Do you consider such approach?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev oh, that's a fun idea!!

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you can't invoke default interface method implementation in inheriting class (though there were [proposals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#base-interface-invocations)). But you can call it from inheriting interface:

```
public class HappyGreeter : IGreeter
{
    private interface IWorkAround : IGreeter
    {
        public void SayHello(string name)
        {
            (this as IGreeter).SayHello(name);
            System.Console.WriteLine("I hope you're doing great!!");
        }
    }

    private class WorkAround : IWorkAround {}

    public void SayHello(string name)
    {
        ((IWorkAround)new WorkAround()).SayHello(name);
    }
}
```

**UPD**

In my original answer I was to much focused on showing that you can call base one in an inheriting interface, but as [@Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov) suggested in comments cleaner way in this particular case would be something like the following:

```
public class HappyGreeter : IGreeter
{
    private class WorkAround : IGreeter { }
    private static readonly IGreeter _workAround = new WorkAround();

    public void SayHello(string name)
    {
        _workAround.SayHello(name);
        System.Console.WriteLine("I hope you're doing great!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: That is disgusting. And genius.

Comment: @mjwills agreed on the first part)))

Comment: It would be nice if I could use `base(IGreeter).SayHello(name)`.

Comment: Nice. Note that you don't need the extra interface if you just want to call the default implementation `class WorkAround: IGrreeter { } ... ((IWorkAround)new WorkAround()).SayHello(name);`

Comment: In my test I get an endless loop and stackoverflow with this

Comment: @RubixCube can you please share a [mre] (I suppose you either casting something wrong or have a cycle in methods). Cause [this works](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHqAUwHcACACQEMAHagTwHExDDhCwAKASgDoBlSnXKEANiID2HAERsAzsClcA3HjyoAzKQCWUNmABmlAMaFSASSYs9eAN55SD0qgAspAUNESOqTAAZSUJQAtoRcpAC8AHxOmDw+AJwcACRSwmLipDaBIQC+AISKKrg5qrgaTugUNPSWrOykIOa11rh2uI6k1GBaAG6UbBWkAOriYADWAIJg4tBwDU3MdWCZpCXtjl29/aY+AGykzJRw4lAidAtW9QD6xKOT07MRASTDd1MzUHDcRfaO5S5uQRpLw+fzZUK/BxtDodG5vB6ffhAzyScHKSEwnxxTCJKRmUgAC3E1FMdBmAHJmKRjjoAOakWmHYB5Aro9YONY5UhAA) as it was at the moment of writing.

Comment: Hmm i think there is a slight difference in my case that may be the cause:

I have something like this (so i'm implementing explicitly an higher interface function):

```
public interface IGreeter
{
    void SayHello(string name)
}

public interface IBaseGreeter
{
    void IGreeter.SayHello(string name) => System.Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}!");
}

public interface IWorkAround : IBaseGreeter
{
    public void IGreeter.SayHello(string name)
    {
        (this as IBaseGreeter).SayHello(name);
        System.Console.WriteLine("I hope you're doing great!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple way to handle this:

1. Declare the default method as static. Don't worry, you will still be able to override it in a class that inherits from it.
2. Call the default method using the same type of syntax when calling a static method of a class, only substitute the interface name for the class name.

This code applies to C#8 or later, and it won't work if building against the .NET Framework. I ran it on Windows 10 with C#9, running on .NET 6, preview 5.

Example:

```
public interface IGreeter
{
   private static int DisplayCount = 0;
   public static void SayHello(string name)
   {
      DisplayCount++;
      Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}! This method has been called {DisplayCount} times.");
   }
}

public class HappyGreeter : IGreeter
{
   public void SayHello(string name)
   {
      // what can I put here to call the default method?
      IGreeter.SayHello(name);
      Console.WriteLine("I hope you're doing great!!");
   }
}

public class CS8NewFeatures
{
   // This class holds the code for the new C# 8 features.
   //
   public void RunTests()
   {
      TestGreeting();
   }

   private void TestGreeting()
   {
      // Tests if a default method may be called after a class has implemented it.
      //
      var hg = new HappyGreeter();
      hg.SayHello("Pippy");
      hg.SayHello("Bob");
      hg.SayHello("Becky");
   }
}
```

Example Output:

```
Hello Pippy! This method has been called 1 times.
I hope you're doing great!!
Hello Bob! This method has been called 2 times.
I hope you're doing great!!
Hello Becky! This method has been called 3 times.
I hope you're doing great!!
```

Static fields are also now allowed in interfaces as this example shows.

If you can't use a static interface method for some reason, then you can always rely on the following technique:

1. Put the default method implementation code into a separate static method.
2. Call this static method from the default implementation method.
3. Call this static method at the top of the class implementation of the interface method.

Example:

```
public class DefaultMethods
{
   // This class is used to show that a static method may be called by a default interface method.
   //
   public static void SayHello(string name) => Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}!");
}

public interface IGreeter
{
   void SayHello(string name) => DefaultMethods.SayHello(name);
}

public class HappyGreeter : IGreeter
{
   public void SayHello(string name)
   {
      // what can I put here to call the default method?
      DefaultMethods.SayHello(name);
      Console.WriteLine("I hope you're doing great!!");
   }
}

public class CS8NewFeatures
{
   // This class holds the code for the new C# 8 features.
   //
   public void RunTests()
   {
      TestGreeting();
   }

   private void TestGreeting()
   {
      // Tests if a default method may be called after a class has implemented it.
      //
      var hg = new HappyGreeter();
      hg.SayHello("Bob");
   }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Hello Bob!
I hope you're doing great!!
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is not an answer to the question, but the next approach also can be used to emulate `base` functionality:

```
public interface IGreeter
{
    void SayHello(string name) => BaseSayHello(name);

    // This static method can be used in implementers of "IGreeter"
    // to emulate "base" functionality.
    protected static void BaseSayHello(string name) => System.Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}!");
}

public class HappyGreeter : IGreeter
{
    public void SayHello(string name)
    {
        IGreeter.BaseSayHello(name);
        Console.WriteLine("I hope you're doing great!!");
    }
}
```