# How can we use default implementation of different interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface, default-interface-member

As I know, I need to upcast an instance of an inherited class to the interface where a needed method is implemented and then call it.

```
interface IProcess
{
    void Do() { Console.WriteLine("doing"); }
    //...
}

interface IWait
{
    void Wait() { Console.WriteLine("waiting"); }
    //...
}

class Example : IProcess, IWait { }


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Example item = new Example();
    (item as IProcess).Do();
    (item as IWait).Wait();
}
```

What if there are few interfaces with default implementation of different methods that I need? Is there some pattern that can solve this or maybe I should always use *as* keyword to call a method of a certain interface?

Comment: `as` folowed by `.` doesn't make sense. Either do a standard cast if you're sure of interface existence, or use `.?` if you're not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option in addition to [@DavGarcia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40161/davgarcia)'s answer - introduce an interface combining the needed ones and upcast to it:

```
interface IExample : IProcess, IWait { }    
class Example : IExample { }

IExample item = new Example();
item.Do();
item.Wait();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only calling the method once, I would do it like below. As ugly as it is, it is correct.

```
((IProcess)item).Do();
```

There are some other options that may be cleaner if you need to call more than once. You can convert to the interface:

```
IProcess itemProcess = item;
itemProcess.Do(); // Now call many times.
```

Usually though, I think you would be passing the object into a function that expects the interface:

```
void DoSomething(IProcess itemProcess) {
    itemProcess.Do();
}

DoSomething(item);
```

Comment: It seems that you can even declare an extension method [with the same signature](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z6IGZo) and it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can override the methods in the implementing class and pass through control to the default implementation.

```
interface IProcess
{
    void Do() { Console.WriteLine("doing"); }
}

interface IWait
{
    void Wait() { Console.WriteLine("waiting"); }
}

class Example : IProcess, IWait 
{
    public void Do() => ((IProcess)this).Do();

    public void Wait() => ((IWait)this).Wait();
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Example item = new Example();
    item.Do();
    item.Wait();
}
```

Comment: Actually you can't - it will end with SO. AFAIK there are no way ATM to call default interface  in it's implementation, only some [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62334580/2501279)

Comment: Are you sure? See [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57761990/2791540).

Comment: Yes, I am. In this answer default interface is called in another method, not in the implementation of itself.