# How can I extend multiple classes in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have two classes, is it possible to create a third class that extends both of them?

```
abstract class A {
    name
    age
    protected abstract print()
}
        
abstract class B {
    name
    age
}
        
// class C needs to inherit from both of the above classes

class C extends A , B {
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to extend two or more classes at the same time. Multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java. You can use interfaces. In this case the class c can implement the interface A and B, for example.

Comment: the manual is well done https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html

Comment: @ABOS in what way is TS multiple inheritance similar to Java?

Comment: @VLAZ man i don't know what you trying to prove here it's obvious that tag was added by mistake

Comment: @danielwix ABOS edited the title of your question to add "similar to Java" therefore linking your query back to the apparently unrelated language. Also, it's not really "obvious" it was a mistake. We get questions with weird mixes of tags every day. Yes, a lot are a mistake but without the ability to read the mind of the question asker, we don't *know* whether they've added a tag because they meant to or not. When in doubt, I prefer to ask. Who knows, maybe you wanted to emulate some Java construct you had but in TS. We get similar questions also on a daily basis.

Comment: all good @VLAZ but for a simple question i am getting downvotes rather than answers haha

Comment: [It's not a simple problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/225929/) It's one of the funamental issues in OOP design. You can't just be solved. Like that. Some languages have "solved" it by forbidding it altogether. Java *used to* be like that. With default method bodies it is in some ways possible to inherit from multiple unrelated taxonomies, ***however***, it is a compilation error if both ancestors declare the same method. Thus there isn't really a "solved" multiple inheritance even then in Java, just loosened restrictions around it. Moreover, with the example you've shown, there is no

Comment: reason to use multiple inheritance - presumably both `A` and `B` can have a common ancestor, thus `C` would not need to inherit from both. Or `C` can simply inherit from `A`. There is little reason for `C` to be a subtype of `B` here. And if it *does* then your example does not seem representative. In JS (and TS after bypassing some of it) it's possible to "splice" multiple ancestors into the prototype chain which is *sort of* like multiple inheritance. But doesn't "solve" it, either. It's brute forcing it in. So, hard to solve a design issue without a real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, depending on the requirements there are several ways to do this.  Given the classes `A` and `B`:

```js
class A {
  constructor(public i: number){}
  foo() {
    return 123;
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(public name: string){}
  bar() {
    return "Hello from B!";
  }
}
```

you can do any of the following and have it *just work* (for some value of just-work):

1. Inherit one class, *implement* the other as an interface (in TypeScript any class may be treated as an interface):

   ```js
   class Cv1 extends B implements A { /* implement A-as-interface here */ }
   ```
2. Create a type alias for `A & B` and implement the type alias (e. g. treat *both* classes as interfaces):

   ```js
   type AandB = A & B;
   class Cv2 implements AandB {
     constructor(public i: number, public name: string) {}
     foo(...args: []) {
       return A.prototype.foo.apply(this, args);
     }
     bar() {
       return "Cv2 says GOODBYE!";
     }
   }
   ```
3. Mix both classes together and inherit from the mixed class:

   ```js
   // Exercise for the reader: do it without any
   function mixin(a: any, b: any): any {
     // Choice: Should isA apply to either mixin? Should it apply to neither?
     const aNotB = Object.defineProperties(Object.create(a.prototype), Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(b.prototype));
     const shadowClass: any = function shadowClass(){}
     shadowClass.prototype = aNotB;
     class mixinImpl extends shadowClass {}
     return mixinImpl;
   }

   class Cv3 extends mixin(A, B) { }
   ```

#### Caveat Emptor

There are limitations with this technique.  For example, if `B` has a prototype chain of its own (e. g. `B extends BPrime` and `BPrime extends BPrimordial`, etc.) then none of the methods and properties of `BPrime` and `BPrimordial` will be copied over (you can walk the prototype chain yourself at class construction time to work around this if that's what you want to do).  Also, `instanceof` will not work with any of the `implements` or `.assign` techniques (e. g. `anInstanceOfC instanceof B` will be `false` using any of the techniques above).